# update context parameter value from get_queryset () django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

my code is

```
class Leads(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

def get_queryset(self):
q = self.request.GET.get('q', "all")
        if q == "customer":
            qs = alllead.objects.filter(isCustomer="yes")
        elif q == "lead":
            qs = alllead.objects.filter(isCustomer="no")
        else:
            qs = self.queryset
return qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Leads, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    count = self.queryset.count()
    context['count'] = count or "000"
return context
```

so i am filtering my queryset and also i need to set record count as context parameter "count"
but the number of record is not updating
so i have changed my code to

```
def get_queryset(self):
q = self.request.GET.get('q', "all")
        if q == "customer":
            qs = alllead.objects.filter(isCustomer="yes")
        elif q == "lead":
            qs = alllead.objects.filter(isCustomer="no")
        else:
            qs = self.queryset
return qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Leads, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     q = self.request.GET.get('q', "none")
     if q == "customer":
         count = alllead.objects.filter(isCustomer="yes").count()
     elif q == "lead":
         count = alllead.objects.filter(isCustomer="no").count()
     else:
         count = self.queryset.count()
     context['count'] = count or "000"
return context
```

i think i am duplicating code and this is not the proper way to do it.
can anyone suggest me the optimal way to update

```
context['count'] = qs.count()
#inside get_queryset()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've called the superclass `get_queryset()`, then the qs is added to the context as `alllead_list`; you can just access it from there.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Leads, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    count = context['alllead_list'].count()
```

However, I don't think you need to do this in the view at all; you can just as easily do this in the template by accessing `{{ allead_list.count|default:"000" }}`.

**Edit** Since the queryset is paginated, you can get the count directly from the paginator: `context['paginator'].count` or in the template `{{ paginator.count }}`.

Comment: Thank You very much i have changed my template
`{{ object_list.count|default:"0" }}`

but it shows only 25? which is current paginated objects?

Comment: `count = context['alllead_list'].count()` this sollution also gives number of current paginated objects 25

Comment: `{{ paginator.count }}` works for me. 
it solves my problem in just one line

Comment: @danial Roseman, from where i can get the documentation like which context parameters are default used by class based views?
because i never read about context['paginator'] and context['*_list']?